# Python Salesforce connection

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, simple-salesforce

I have problem connecting to Salesforce in Anaconda in the below code :

Code:

```
session_id, instance = SalesforceLogin(username=user_name, password=pass_word, organizationId=org_id, security_token='')
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnsupportedExtension'

IDE: SPYDER

Answer (score 1):

There are also **two** means of **authentication**, one that uses username, password and security token and the other that uses IP filtering, username, password and organizationId.

**First:**

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='myemail@example.com', password='password', security_token='token')
```

**Second:**

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(password='password', username='myemail@example.com', organizationId='OrgId')
```

For more information visit: https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/

Comment: Hi Adam , I have used the First & Second solution, but both are still giving the error .

Comment: File "C:\Users\AG47552\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 202, in get_subj_alt_name

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnsupportedExtension'